Power line crossing data lines via the ground plane
Sorry if this is a stupid questions. I have searched this and have not found a direct answer.

I am designing a Stm32 based board, mainly referencing this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aVUqaB0IMh4
My questions is; is it ok to cross 3.3v power across data lines? The power line travels to the ground plane with a via, crosses the data lines and comes back up.

it's less about the fact that these are power traces, it's problematic because now the return current for these data lines can't travel directly below them, but needs to take a shared detour around that slot in the ground plane.
For low speed signals that might be OK, for signals with a fast rising edge, not so much.

Hey @marcus-müller,
Can you please expand on, "needs to take a shared detour"?
So there data lines are button GPIO inputs, with a pull up resistor. Do you mean when the button is pressed it will now take longer for the pin to register as a 0/GND?

@Newbi_EE: A button press signal is an example of a low-speed signal. So, as the last line states, it doesn't matter for you. If your data line is a USB2 data line, it does matter.

@Newbi_EE as MSalters says, button presses are incredibly slow, and you won't notice the difference in speed. The problem is this: remember that the power in a changing signal on a conductor doesn't travel in the conductor, but in the electric field between the conductor and its environment. You want to have a well-defined path of travel for that energy, so you put ground below such traces: then nearly all the energy is in the gap between ground and your trace, it doesn't leak significantly much into its environment and doesn't couple into other traces. Now, when you cut a slot into your

ground plane, that stops to work, and instead of being the narrow gap between top layer and ground layer, your electric field fields the space between the nearest ground-referenced potential. Meaning that instead of nice nearly purely vertical electrical field lines between top layer and ground layer that never intermingle, you now have electric field lines of multiple traces, all going to the edges of your ground slot. Suddenly, they are not independent anymore, and you see the things you send on one trace on the others (and vice versa). Depending on how sharp the edges of your data lines are

you also might have built a slot antenna and might be radiating RF from that place, to disturb all your other electronics. Not great! Now, you ask about buttons. As said, buttons are incredibly slow compared to digital data signals. Don't worry about button lines. For pushbuttons, this is incredibly fine, and you can use this perfectly well. Still follow Voltage Spike's advice to add enough decoupling capacitors to each chip you use. But other than that, it's OK.

@Newbi_EE: Put simply: Remember that current doesn’t only travel in the positive wire but also needs a return path in the negative (ground) wire. Beginners tend to look closely at all the positive traces but then neglect the ground connection (because it’s seemingly taken care by the ground pour anyway). When you slice up your ground plane it makes the return path longer. Doesn’t really matter for a slow, strong signal like a button though.

If you need to do this in two layers, you can reduce the impact of the gap by routing a ground line on the top layer.
Ideally you will route it from the source of the signals to the destination (orange line), but even just routing it over the gap (yellow line) helps:


A useful guideline I've heard is that one's primary focus should be on reducing the length of the longest slot.  I think the above example could use another "staple" or two, but the benefit of even just one you added would probably be as great as the combined benefit of adding many more.

It's fine to do that, with caveats. But one problem is trace inductance and bypass caps. Make sure you have the recommended bypass capacitors next to all the STM32 pins. In addition you may want to parallel vias, this will lower inductance to the 3.3V line. More inductance makes it hard to source power to the power pins. Also having wider power traces can lower inductance to the power pins.
If you don't need fast signalling (like above 5Mhz) then this cut is fine, if you do need fast signalling this could slow rise times down. Its hard to say exactly how it will affect the rise times, but they will be slower. Cut's into the ground plane very big as the return currents on digital lines and increase inductance on the ground plane (which carries return currents, most of the current is directly beneath the digital line).
But reallly, 4 layer boards aren't that much more expensive, if you need speed or low noise, then switch to a 4 layer board.

Hey @Voltage
Thanks for the info. Few more questions for you:
Can you eleborate on parallel vias or point me towards a resource I can read?
My stm32 controller is running at 73 Mhz, I am not sure if this is what you mean by signaling?
Finally is it generally ok to branch out the power line?
Thanks!

@Newbi_EE You are running some kind of signals on the GPIO traces, no? What are you running on those traces, you ought to know what speeds you need. I usually avoid layer changes with power lines, but sometimes it's unavoidable I usaually do two or three vias, if I have room I do a 20 or 30 mil traces which is overkill but I don't have to worry or calculate the current draw or inductance/resistance of the traces.

The GOIPs are connected to buttons with a pullup resistors and denounce circuit attached. Sorry I am still learning, I had no idea about speeds up until now.
These are .5 mm traces which comes out 19.685 mil. Here is whats on the other end of the trace: https://i.sstatic.net/oJ2QtKjA.png
Also took your advice and started on a 4 layer board, it seems much much cleaner way of doing things.

Missing "not" I assume: "If you do not need fast signalling (like above 5Mhz) then this cut is fine, if you do need fast signalling..." in the 2nd para.  I thought it was too small for me to edit by I could and have
